# sh script for executing mysql script with entering pass

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, mysql, database

I'd like to execute a mysql script where user is asked to enter the password dynamically from the command line.
If possible with a message `Enter your $root password`
However it doesn't work as expected so far I have

```
mysql -u root -p CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test
```

moreover when the db is created how to logout from mysql and go back to bash commands?

Comment: Also posted on askubuntu.com: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077725/sh-script-for-executing-mysql-script-with-entering-pass

Comment: Hello Jocky Doe. Your question is currently likely to get closed because it's been posted on two different StackExchange websites. Please choose one, and delete the other question. (Or wait, and it'll probably get closed here anyway.)

Comment: The AU one has an accepted Answer, so I suspect the U&L one should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Test" | mysql -u root -p
```

It will prompt for the password, execute the command, and return to the shell.